# Does anybody encounter this bug ? formula should return 0 but return 5,6843418860808E-14

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I got thjis ultra simple formula in cell F2 = F1-E2+D2.
it is simply to calculate balance of an account from debit and credit amounts : old new balance = old balance - debit + credit

But, if F1 = n,  E2 = n and D2 = 0, formula should return 0 but it returns 5,6843418860808E-14 instead....
Excel is able to correctly tell me that F1 = E2 is true...

I probably can do a workaround using round or other trunc fucntions but...

IT IS CLEARLY A BUG... and inmpossible to tell MS as I do not have any support plan.. :( that sucks

Comment: And what exactly is `n` in this case? Computers generally use IEEE 754 floating point numbers. Combined with rounding errors, this may result in “strange” results.

Comment: You don't need a support plan to provide [feedback to Excel](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/How-do-I-give-feedback-on-Microsoft-Office-2b102d44-b43f-4dd2-9ff4-23cf144cfb11).

Comment: It's **NOT** a bug. Please read [The Floating-Point Guide - What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)

Comment: I'm wondering that you got `5,6843418860808E-14`,,, coz the Formula should return the `#Value` error instead of ZERO !!